# Queries with left join returns fewer rows

Tags: sql, symfony, doctrine, left-join

Using Doctrine in a Symfony project confuses me. When requesting all rows from a single entity I get a higher number of rows than I get when I join the same table with another.

This is returning more rows:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('obj')
    ->from('AppBundle:Data', 'obj');
```

Than this:

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();
$query->select('obj')
    ->from('AppBundle:Data', 'obj')
    ->leftJoin('obj.subDatas', 'sd')
    ->leftJoin('sd.subSubDatas', 'ssd');
```

How could it be so? I guess that this could be the case with an innerJoin, but I thought that the result would be at least as many, or maybe more rows when using a leftJoin.

Is this expected?

UPDATE

So I figured that the actual cause of this confusion seems to be the pagination added after the query above:

```
$query
    ->setMaxResults(20)
    ->setFirstResult(0);
```

It seems that this is not working well with leftJoin used above (which is why the result count is correct in the first example). How do I make it return the correct number of rows when using leftJoins?

Comment: You can use a `return $query->getResult()->getSQL()` at the end of the repo method and see what actual sql code is generated; for debug purposes.

Comment: Yes, a left join must return at least as many rows as an inner join on the same condition and at least as many rows as the left table. But without a [mcve] we don't really know what the input & output were.

Comment: I corrected the bd reference and added a question about pagination which seems to be the problem, in my question above.

Comment: Please always keep a post self-contained & up-to-date. Don't just tack more on the end, contradicting & obviating what precedes it. (Past versions are available via the 'edited' link.) What does "correct number" mean? All of them? If you want all rows then why are you asking for 20? Just don't give a maximum number of rows. **[mcve]** please.

Comment: theva: Use @ to notify a particular commenter when there is more than one. Eg @Matteo.

Comment: hi @philipxy may i help?

Comment: @Matteo The asker fixed a typo you pointed out (that I flagged as no longer needed). I was telling them that they hadn't notified anyone. Thought you might like another look at the question and figured they meant to notify you, so I did.

Answer (score 1):

If your left joins are toMany relationships it is the common cartesian product in SQL. Rows from `obj` get expanded with all the possible values of `sd` and `ssd`.

If you want to paginate a query with toMany relationships in DQL, you need a proper paginator that deal with the doctrine hydration.

Comment: Ok! I found out about Doctrine Paginator http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.5/class-Doctrine.ORM.Tools.Pagination.Paginator.html but I could not get it to work with my query either, it just returned empty results... Is that someting that should be useful here?

Comment: Show your entire query, that would be much easier to get help :)